# protobuf-net using base class instead of derived class when generic class in inheritance chain

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0, protobuf-net

We are using protobuf-net for serialization with WCF services on the following classes.

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(NamedViewModel))]
public class NamedViewModel<TKey> : IViewModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(ScheduleTemplateViewModel))]
public class NamedViewModel : NamedViewModel<int>
{
}

[DataContract]
public class ScheduleTemplateViewModel : NamedViewModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

We have a custom routine that basically does (simplified for brevity).

```
type.GetAttributes<KnownTypeAttribute>().Select(a => a.Type).Distinct().ForEach(t => AddKnownTypeHierarchy(t));  

public static void AddKnownTypeHierarchy(Type type)
{

    ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType metaType = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(type, true);
    ...
    metaType.AddSubType( ...
    ...
}
```

We are getting the following error on the WCF services.

```
{"Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.NamedViewModel`1Proxy' to type 'Presentation.ViewModels.ScheduleTemplateBuilder.ScheduleTemplateViewModel'."}
```

How can this issue be resolved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is using a castle proxy of `Castle.Proxies.NamedViewModel\`1Proxy` - from that it is hard for me to see what the actual type is that is being represented. What is the object that you are trying to send here? Additional thought: the keys / field-numbers used in `AddSubType` are very important - you may want to consider whether you can *reliably* ensure you are getting the same numbers every time your app starts - is there an explicit OrderBy? what happens when someone adds a new type? etc?

Comment: We updated the logic inside AddKnownTypeHierarchy to ensure that the field numbers are unique throughout the hierarchy chain. That resolved the issue.